# Change type of a model field in Odoo preserving old records

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have model classes:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.video'

    category_id = fields.Many2one('my.category')
    # fields

class Category(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.category'

    # fields
```

Now in Video model I want to change the relationship

```
category_id = fields.Many2one('my.category')
```

to

```
category_id = fields.Many2many('my.category')
```

But the problem is I have a live project. So there are records in Video model with category assigned to each video. I cannot loose these records and I will need old categories set for videos in new Many2many relation.
So what is the best way to replace the field while preserving the previous records in a way these records are usable with the new design (relation) too. Or how can I migrate records from previous field to new field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Muhammad Tahir Butt,

Create a New field named :

```
category_ids = fields.Many2many('my.category')
```

Now write some external script using XMLRPC Client lib and just move values from **category_id** to **category_ids**. this way you will preserver past values on old field and then by copying values old field to new field you will have field with existing record.

Bests